# Django translations with parler - show default language text when adding translation

Tags: django, django-i18n, django-parler

I'm working on a Django CMS with content to be translated into multiple languages. I'm using [django-parler](https://django-parler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

To make the translations easier I would like to have the text from the default language visible when adding the translated text, preferable just above the input field/textarea.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `get_form` method in the Admin class, and update the widgets `placeholder` attribute. For example, if I have the folllowing model:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields

class KeyCard(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        series=models.CharField(_('series'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True),
        skill=models.CharField(_('skill'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True),
    )
```

Then I can use

```
from django.contrib import admin
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin
from parler.utils.context import switch_language

@admin.register(KeyCard)
class GuideAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        with switch_language(obj, 'de'):
            for field in ['series', 'skill']:
                form.base_fields[field].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = getattr(obj, field)
        return form
```

Where `de` is my default language, and the fields `series` and `skill` are translatable fields.

[image: Django admin panel, with placeholders for the translations.]

Now this creates `placeholders`, which will disappear when typing, alternatively you can use:

```
form.base_fields[field].widget.attrs['value'] = getattr(obj, field)
```

To get the actuall value there, such that you can directly save it.

Now if you don't want to keep track of the translatable fields yourself, you can use:

```
for field in obj._parler_meta.get_all_fields():
    form.base_fields[field].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = getattr(obj, field)
```

Which will get you all translatable fields.

Note:

- `value` won't work on `models.TextField`